# How do I say ‘It looks to me’ in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say ‘It looks to me’  in Spanish? I'd like to say it in this context: “It looks to me that I am going to Spain again.”

Comment: -1, SLU is no translation service. (On the other hand, [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/how-do-i-say-it-looks-like) you wanted to go to Germany, now Spain! :D )

Comment: In my opinion, this phrase could be useful for other users.

Comment: This would be a better question if you offered your own translation "try." If you said, "I think the expression is 'yo parezco' " (wrong), the question would be ok. At SE, we are here to correct your efforts, but not to teach from scratch.

Comment: @JoulSauron: Please see my meta question: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/321/how-do-we-deal-with-how-do-you-say-questions

Answer (score 2):

'Me parece'

"Me parece que iré a España de nuevo"

Answer (score 1):

Me parece, 'Me Parece que voy a ir a Espana otra vez'
or

Parece, 'Parece que... '

A very popular way to say it is; 'creo'  As in 'Creo que voy a ir a Espana otra vez'

An extremely common and informal way is 'Para mi' As in 'Para mi que voy a ir a Espana otra vez'